# beesel function i want to plot acoustic wave in terms of pressure vs x

Tags: acoustics

C1*Bessel J(0, (500/166203941)*sqrt(-Pi)*sqrt(-1828243351+332407882*x))+C2*Bessel Y(0, (500/166203941)*sqrt(-Pi)*sqrt(-1828243351+332407882*x))

upper one is my solution through maple

i want to plot it please help i hv to submit my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

See this page for basics on plotting with Maple http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~scott/Book331/Plotting_with_Maple.html

First and second kind Bessel functions you need are available as built-ins in Maple: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Bessel

You need to specify the plot range for x, by the way.

Comment: first of all thanks for replying sir. in my case nu is zero and z is complex number , here i want to vary x so that i will get range of z.so how to take care of variation of z.